# Make prototype accessible in vuex

Tags: javascript, vue.js, prototype, vuex

In my `app.js` file I build this so I can use translation in vue:

```
Vue.prototype.trans = string => _.get(window.i18n, string);
```

This is working great in my vue files:

```
{{ trans('translation.name') }}
```

The problem is that I'm using `vuex` and I need to translate some things in a module:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';

Vue.use(Vuex);

export default {
    namespaced: true,

    state: {
        page: 1,
        criterias: [
            {
                name: this.trans('translation.name'),
                filter: "life",
                active: false
            }
     }
 }
```

But here `this.trans('translation.name')` is not working. How could I get this to work?

Comment: A workaround, could be create a sepated .js with your prototype and the `import Vue from 'vue'` and importing this file into your store.js instead of `node_modules/vue`

Comment: `Vue.trans('translation.name')` instead of `this.trans('translation.name')`

Comment: Both not working unfortunately

Comment: Isn't `this._vm.trans` working instead?

Comment: Nope it does not work :(

Comment: Why do not you add `Vue.prototype.trans = string => _.get(window.i18n, string);` to your Vuex module ?

Comment: It won't work like that. You're calling `this.trans()` at the moment of `export default ...` instead of runtime, thus `this` points to the module itself, not the Vue instance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would call mutating Vuex prototype as a bad practice and in this case, it's really not necessary.

Simply create a file called `localization.js` and instantiate the i18n plugin in that file. Plus export a named function to return the same i18n instance.

```
// localization.js

const i18n = new VueI18n({ ... });

export const getLocalization = () => i18n;

export default i18n;
```

Then in your Vuex module import the `getLocalization` function and execute it to get the same `i18n` instance and do translations using it.

```
// vuex-module.js

import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import { getLocalization } from './localization';

Vue.use(Vuex);

const i18n = getLocalization();

export default {
  state: {
    criteria: i18n('translation.name'),
  },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you a workaround. You can move the initialization of `criterias` from `store.js` to your `App.vue`, using a mutation.

store.js

```
state: {
    page: 1,
    criterias: []
},

mutations: {

    setCriterias(state, payload) {
        state.criterias = payload;
    },

}
```

App.vue

```
beforeMount() {

   this.$store.commit( 'setCriterias' , [

        {
            name: this.trans('translation.name'),
            filter: "life",
            active: false
        }

   ])

}
```

Comment: Thanks, but is there really no other way? Because I have a lot of criteria's. My app.vue would become pretty messy :)

Answer (score 0):

As your translation content `window.i18n` is global anyhow, why not define another `trans` method similar to the one you add to `Vue.prototype` in your store module?

If you are concerned about having to edit this method in two places later on, define a translation module with this one method and use it on both places, where you set Vue.prototype and inside your store module.